# MYSQL Insert Ignore on one column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to use the insert ignore statement to put a name in a database. I do not want to create duplicates, however, the insert ignore statement I use keeps inserting!

The statement is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO firstname(name) VALUES ('Tommy')
```

My database shows this:

```
id  |  name
-------------
1      Tommy
2      Tommy
3      Tommy
```

A couple bits of information for people helping me. My id is my primary key and it is auto incremented.

My guess is that because the new id is created automatically it thinks its a new result! I am not sure how to solve this expcept with a bigger SQL query checking if the name Tommy exists first

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the column `name` from `firstname` table is `not unique`. Try to add `unique` constraint using this DDL statement,

```
ALTER TABLE firstname ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

then try if it still add duplicate name. Hope it works now :)

Comment: I have done this and that works great. Would you still use INSERT IGNORE or just use INSERT?

Comment: you can still use `INSERT IGNORE` :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set 'unique key' constraint on 'name' column?

Answer (score 0):

Given your schema, using `IGNORE` makes no difference. `IGNORE` is used to ignore potential errors raised during the insertion.

To avoid duplicates in the name column, add a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column and drop the `IGNORE` keyword from the `INSERT` statement. If you keep using the `IGNORE`, the `UNIQUE` constraint will cause an error but it will be ignored which means in fact that the `UNIQUE` constraint will be ignored.