# Update a row, but insert if row doesn't exist in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to do an insert of row in a table, like this:

```
$this->db->update_batch($this->table_name, $update, 'image_id');

if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 0) {
    $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_name, $update);
}
```

but if it exists **I don't want to do anything**. But this code above inserts another row because no row is affected

I guess I could do a *INSERT IGNORE INTO* but I would prefer using CodeIgniters **upate_batch** and **insert_batch**.

`$update` - variable is something like

```
$update = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Gustav'),
   array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)
```

**UPDATE**

By the answers I get that I wasn't clear enough in what I wanted. (and I didn't think I was clear enough what I wanted so here is my updated question which I hope is clearer)

```
//This will insert Gustav, Peter and Lisa

$update = array(
   array('image_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Gustav'),
   array('image_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('image_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)
$this->db->insert_batch($update);


//If I do this it would insert Party Gustav, Peter and Lisa.
$update = array(
   array('image_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Party Gustav'),
   array('image_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('image_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)
$this->db->insert_batch($update);

//Above will create 6 rows
```

**BUT what I want to happen IS**

```
$update = array(
   array('image_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Gustav'),
   array('image_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('image_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)
$this->db->insert_batch($update);

$update = array(
   array('image_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Party Gustav'),
   array('image_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('image_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)


//Insert batch but when existing image_ids just change the name 
//from Gustav to Party Gustav (in this case)
$this->db->insert_batch($update); 

//Above will create 3 rows
```

I guess it will equal to something like `on key duplicate` for `insert_batch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Select all image_id from the table.**

```
$data = $this->db->select(`image_id`)->get($this->table_name)->result_array();
```

**List image_id into an array.**

```
$image_ids=array();

foreach($data as $key => $value):

$image_ids[$key]=$value[`image_id`];

endforeach;

$update = array(
   array('image_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Party Gustav'),
   array('image_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Peter'),
   array('image_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Lisa')
)
```

**Check if the image_ids exist:**

```
$update_query= $this->db->where_in(`image_ids`,$image_ids)
               ->get($this->table_name)->result();

if($update_query->num_rows() > 0):

  $this->db->update_batch($update,$this->table_name);//update if ids exist
else
   $this->db->insert_batch($update,$this->table_name);//insert if does not exist
endif;
```

Comment: Yes sometimes even simpler solutions are great. Looks great, so I accept this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is `INSERT IGNORE INTO`. Unfortunately, Codeigniter doesn't have an equivalent Active Record function. A [discussion on the Codeigniter forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/168698/#805401) and this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965792/insert-ignore-using-codeigniter) suggest a method like this:

```
foreach ($update as $update_item) {
    $insert_query = $this->db->insert_string($this->table_name, $update_data['name']);
    $insert_query = str_replace('INSERT INTO','INSERT IGNORE INTO',$insert_query);
    $this->db->query($insert_query);  
}
```

Also note that the `image_id` [must be `UNIQUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913417/144194).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used codeigniter, but could you check to see if the row exist first, and then either update or insert?

Comment: Yes, I could do that. but because $update array can contain a lot of image_ids there could be a lot of request to the db and I cant afford that.