# How to update_batch along with insert_batch new entries in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way to update bulk entries and insert new entries if does not exist (bulk) using codeigniter or custom MYSQL query ?

```
$dynamic_data= array();
 for($count = 0; $count <= count($_POST["descp"]); $count++){   
         if(!empty($_POST["descp"][$count])){ 
            array_push( $dynamic_data,array(
            'id'=>$_POST["ctq_meta_id"][$count],
            'ctq_id'=>$ctq_id,
            'descp'=> $_POST["descp"][$count], 
            'date_since'=>$_POST["date_since"][$count],
            'risk'=>$_POST["risk"][$count],
            'loss'=>$_POST["loss"][$count],
            'created_at'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            )); 

            } 

            } 

$this->db->update_batch($this->meta_table,$meta_data,'id');
```

This is for update just and working fine but does not add new entries.

**Required**: Required any method which can update the existing records and insert the new bulk records ***without pre-fetching*** like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049652/update-a-row-but-insert-if-row-doesnt-exist-in-codeigniter) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a row, but insert if row doesn't exist in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049652/update-a-row-but-insert-if-row-doesnt-exist-in-codeigniter)

Comment: in dup, same example given, please try

Comment: @devpro This is pre-fetches results using php code, I don't want to pre-fetch the records because there is huge data. I am assuming ther must be a way to achieve this inside the Sql or codeigniter built in methods.

Comment: no , i  think u need to create your own custom method